# Algorithm for Predicting Battery lifetime

Tags: algorithm

I want to write an algorithm for nodes in wireless network. Assuming there are several nodes who runs with battery and there is a base station who tracks the battery status of the nodes. The aim of the base station is to predict accurately which node needs to recharge first. Now power consumption rate are different from node to node. So even though 2 of the node's batter are at 30% does not mean they need to be recharged at the same time.

How can I form an algorithm so that the base station can predict which node is gonna last longer? I am thinking about 'Reinforced Learning' based algorithm. Is there any other approach that will be suited for this criteria? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you could go with something simple and improve as required. Don't directly go with popular "learning" algorithms.

Comment: Well, you can use simple regression, assuming your base station "knows" the electricity status of all its nodes, it can observe for enough time on the different nodes, and create a model for each, that predicts given a status on the battery on one node, how long will it take for it to discharge. This is simple regression algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

**your title is a bit misleading**

- `Prediction of Battery lifetime` means predicting the Battery usable capacity change after (dis)charge cycles, temperature/voltage/current shocks etc ...
- It is used to estimate how long the battery will be usable and needed to be changed after ...

**For your task I would avoid complicated learning algorithms with uncertain results by:**

1. measure the average dependency of power consumption vs:

   - traffic
   - local temperature
   - form a 2D table and then use it for extrapolation of charge during runtime
2. measure the efficiency of power conversion of each node

   - some cheap power supplies DC/DC are less efficient when the battery voltage drops
   - if you add this to equation your results will improve a lot
   - temperature is a big influence here
   - low temperatures increase the capacity of battery
   - dropping its voltage to compensate
   - high temperatures are a bit dangerous for fully charged batteries
   - as it drops max capacity the charge can be higher then max capacity damaging battery
   - and sometimes resulting higher voltage can even destroy the DC/DC gradually (if it is not build to handle over voltage)

**Then in each iteration per node/time step:**

1. compute/extrapolate actual capacity
2. if overcharged limit estimated charge
3. compute/extrapolate actual power consumption (depending on temperature,traffic)
4. substract actual `power_consumption*time_step` from estimated charge
5. loop until charge/voltage is below limit
6. count the iterations (that is the time the charge will suffice)